# Get rid of rounded corners of Round Rect Button (MonoTouch)

Tags: iphone, uibutton, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I want to get rid of the rounded corners of a UIButton (type = Round Rect Button).  I want to stack some buttons to give a UITableView look and want to get rid of the rounded corners in some instances.  Is this possible?  (MonoTouch)

Answer (score 1):

If th type is rounded rect, it has the rouded corner. Use a custom type to do exactly what you want.

If you're in interface builder, just select custom type, you can then use a background image or normal layer attributes (border, shadow...).

In code, don't create a new classe, jsut create a button and set the type to custom.

Comment: Ok, so I would create a class that implements UIButton and set the type to custom, but what would the rest of the code look like?  The code that actually created the corners, etc.?

Comment: If you're in interface builder, just select custom type, you can then use a background image or normal layer attributes (border, shadow...). In code, don't create a new classe, jsut create a button and set the type to custom.

Answer (score 0):

Create the image of the button you want (in Photoshop, or whatever else floats your boat), change the button type to "Custom" and then import the created image to your project and set it under the "Image:" drop down in Interface Builder.

Tada, customization complete.

Comment: Wouldn't this require 2 images though?  One for Retina and one for non-Retina?

Comment: @BrianDavidBerman easy enough to fix, create the first button, save it as the `@2x` version, and then scale it down. No biggie. You're going to run into that regardless of how you choose to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `UIButtonType` to see all the types of button you can create (including a custom one). E.g.

```
var b = new UIButton ();    
b.ButtonType = UIButtonType.Custom;
```

OTOH if you want to do things that looks like UITableView then I strongly suggest you to look at [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) and its sample application - which includes ownerdraw elements. It will be as easy (or easier) than dealing with several buttons (and **much** easier than using `UITableView`).

Comment: At least in MonoTouch v3.0.4, `ButtonType` is read-only. There may be other ways to do so, but you can create it with `Custom` preset from the static factory methods: `var b = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);`